# MySql Ordered Keyword Search

Tags: mysql, search, join

I have two tables currently:

search_matches:

```
match_id (int) <-- primary key
parent_id (int) <-- foreign-key
word_id (int) <-- foreign-key (to a table filled with words that are unique and have an id)
pos (int) <-- the position of the word in the block of text it comes from
```

search_words: (update)

```
word_id (int) <-- primary key
word (varchar ...) <-- the word
```

(I'm using innodb, and my host won't upgrade mysql, so fulltext is out)

I'd like to be able for my users to search using ". So that they can search for "foo bar".

I've thought of a few ways of doing this, but the least intensive seems to be adding another column:

```
next_pos (int)
```

I could then do

```
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE word_id='foo') as foo
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM table WHERE word_id='bar') AS bar 
ON (
  foo.parent_id=bar.parent_id AND
  foo.next_pos=bar.next_pos
)
```

It comes at the cost of storing an extra column and an inner join for each word beyond the first, but its the best option I've come up with so far. (The idea previous to this was one less column, but needing to do an addition operation within the ON block, something I thought might be too expensive as my site grows.

Is this my best option, or is there another out there? I'm still just playing in staging, so now's the time to make changes.

---

Update 1:

I'm now considering using the keyword table to narrow down my search and then using like on that instead of multiple joins as this may be faster yet and greatly eliminates the need for joins. It just would not be productive to do a like on my entire database.

Answer (score 0):

I really can't understand why do you want to do all this manual work. There are tools out there that can simply it. From what I read what you want to do is related to a full text search. You don't need to build the index yourself.

Have you considered using something like SolR? It works well with any sort of DB as long as you create an index.

Comment: Unfortunately my host won't let me do this with my current package.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see how you are going to make that search with your current set-up.  If as you say you have a table that contains only UNIQUE words from a block of text, how would you expect to correlate this listing of unique words to the actual word placement in the full content?  For example say the original content looked like this:

```
some text with foo and also with foo bar
```

Would you unique word table look like this?

```
word_id   word
--------------
1         some
2         text
3         with
4         foo
5         and
6         also
7         bar
```

If so, how are you ever going to find `foo` and `bar` as adjacent records?

I assume your database also has the full content somewhere, so why not just search in the content using `LIKE`?

Comment: The table of unique values is merely a primary auto incrementing key (word_id) with another column (word) that has the text. {1:some,2:text,3:with,4:foo,5:and,6:also,7:bar} The words don't repeat. I'm worried like could be too expensive.

Comment: @Kirk But if you need to search on meaningful substrings of the full content, there is no way to do it with just a dictionary of all the worlds in the content, unless you know that words would never repeat in that content.

Comment: There are two tables... one is the dictionary. The other contains references to the dictionary with the position of the word in the text it comes from (pos)